# Splitting full-screen apps with AppleScript

Tags: macos, automation, applescript, automator, macos-sierra

I have been using [this script](https://gist.github.com/dsummersl/4175461) in Automator, which toggles apps between full-screen and windowed mode. I am a frequent user of split-screen applications (introduced in El Capitan), so is there any way to modify this script to enable split-screen? I know there's no keyboard shortcut for splitting, so this is definitely a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to cobble something together, working off an AppleScript/python thing that I found in [this MacScripter post](https://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=46154). It does the following:

1. Pulls a list of open application windows from System Events, and allows the user to select one or two (for full screen or split screen)
2. Launches "Mission Control"
3. GUI-scripts the Dock to find references to the various window-buttons and spaces in Mission Control that we need to access
4. Programmatically drags the buttons around to create a new fullscreen or splitscreen space
5. Clicks on the newly created space to activate it

You might be able to trim some time down on all the half-second delays, but Mission Control is expecting human interaction and handles things lazily. It will miss GUI requests that come too fast.

```
(* collect names of open app windows *)
tell application "System Events"
    set windowNames to {}
    set theVisibleProcesses to every process whose visible is true
    repeat with thisProcess in theVisibleProcesses
        set windowNames to windowNames & (name of every window of thisProcess whose role description is "standard window")
    end repeat
end tell

(* choose 1 name for fullscreen, two names for split screen *)
set selectedItems to choose from list windowNames with title "Split It" with prompt "Choose items to add to split view." with multiple selections allowed without empty selection allowed
if selectedItems is false or (count of selectedItems) > 2 then return

set selectedWindow1 to item 1 of selectedItems
if (count of selectedItems) = 2 then
    set selectedWindow2 to item 2 of selectedItems
end if

tell application "Mission Control"
    launch
end tell

(* 
The dock has a set of nested UI elements for Mission Control, with the following structure:
    "Mission Control"'s group 1 (the base container)
        group 1, group 2, .... (groups for each desktop)
            buttons for open windows on each desktop
        group "Spaces Bar" 
            a single button (the '+' buttan to add a new space) 
            a list 
                buttons for the desktops and any already-made spaces 
*)

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Dock"'s group "Mission Control"'s group 1
        tell group "Spaces Bar"'s list 1
            set {p, s} to {position, size} of last UI element
            set XTarget to (item 1 of p) + (item 1 of s) + 100
            set YTarget to (item 2 of p) + (item 2 of s) + 100
        end tell
        tell group 1
            set viewButton1 to button selectedWindow1
            set {x, y} to get viewButton1's position
            my mouseDrag(x, y, XTarget, YTarget, 0.5)
        end tell
        tell group "Spaces Bar"'s list 1
            set {p, s} to {position, size} of last UI element
            set XTarget to (item 1 of p) + (item 1 of s) + 10
            set YTarget to (item 2 of p) + (item 2 of s) + 10
        end tell
        try
            tell group 1
                set viewButton2 to button selectedWindow2
                set {x, y} to get viewButton2's position
                my mouseDrag(x, y, XTarget, YTarget, 0.5)
            end tell
        end try
        tell group "Spaces Bar"'s list 1
            delay 0.5
            set lastUI to last UI element
            click lastUI
        end tell
    end tell
end tell

on mouseDrag(xDown, yDown, xUp, yUp, delayTime)
    do shell script "

/usr/bin/python <<END

from Quartz.CoreGraphics import CGEventCreateMouseEvent
from Quartz.CoreGraphics import CGEventCreate
from Quartz.CoreGraphics import CGEventPost
from Quartz.CoreGraphics import kCGEventLeftMouseDown
from Quartz.CoreGraphics import kCGEventLeftMouseUp
from Quartz.CoreGraphics import kCGMouseButtonLeft
from Quartz.CoreGraphics import kCGHIDEventTap
from Quartz.CoreGraphics import kCGEventLeftMouseDragged
from Quartz.CoreGraphics import kCGEventMouseMoved
import time

def mouseEvent(type, posx, posy):
          theEvent = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(None, type, (posx,posy), kCGMouseButtonLeft)
          CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, theEvent)

def mousemove(posx,posy):
          mouseEvent(kCGEventMouseMoved, posx,posy);

def mousedrag(posx,posy):
          mouseEvent(kCGEventLeftMouseDragged, posx, posy);

def mousedown(posxdown,posydown):
          mouseEvent(kCGEventLeftMouseDown, posxdown,posydown);

def mouseup(posxup,posyup):
      mouseEvent(kCGEventLeftMouseUp, posxup,posyup);

ourEvent = CGEventCreate(None);

mousemove(" & xDown & "," & yDown & ");
mousedown(" & xDown & "," & yDown & ");
time.sleep(" & (delayTime as text) & ");
mousedrag(" & xUp & "," & yUp & ");
time.sleep(" & (delayTime as text) & ");
mouseup(" & xUp & "," & yUp & ");

END"
end mouseDrag
```

Comment: Interesting; however, it doesn't apear to be doing anything different than if I click-hold the full screen button manually to bring up split screen view. Don't get me wrong, I see some potencial use for it, e.g. as a keyboard shortcut and I've made one, but modded the code a bit. I added `set targetApp to (name of every application process whose frontmost is true) as text` and `tell process targetApp`. What would be great is if the code could also select a given app/window in the other side of the split screen view when it initially appears. Do you think you could code something like that?

Comment: I thought about that, but the mechanism is completely opaque, and I can't see a way to get a handle on it. I mean, I can see what it's doing — it's a standard split view with the window selected on one side and a more-or-less standard collection view on the other — but I don't know exactly *what* is presenting the split view. The best possibility I can see is to (somehow) get a list of the views presented in the collection list and programmatically click on the one we want, but so far I haven't been able to make that work. Still playing with it, though; if I figure something out I'll add it.

Comment: Yeah, I've looked at it too and came to the conclusion it will probably take AppleScriptObjC to do it, and I'm just not up on it enough. Anyway +1 for your answer.

Comment: @user3439894: I'm relatively good with ObjC, and I haven't yet found any hooks for this. I've figured out that it's handled by Mission Control, but MC isn't scriptable, it doesn't accept drags, there's no command-line interface, and I haven't yet found a framework that I can access. I've even been poking under Spaces, Expose, and Dashboard to no avail.  It's annoying. If I could figure ASOC I would have, but if you see something I've missed, let me know; I'm curious now.

Comment: Ah, I think I got it. I'll put it in a new answer, for clarity. (PS. scratch that, I'll rewrite my original answer)

Comment: What version of macOS are you running? The first updated code erred out on `set selectedWindow2 to item 2 of selectedItems` with `Can’t get item 2 of {\"...\"}." number -1728 from item 2 of {"..."}`. The latest version, after selecting which window I want in the split view just puts that selected one in full screen view. Thanks! ... Also, I never get any inkling of a split view like I did with the original code.

Comment: I'm on Mojave (10.14.5). Two questions: did you select two windows in the dialog (using the command-key to get them both at once)? And are you sure both of the windows you selected can go full screen? Not every window can, and the ones that can't will fail silently. You got the first error (I think) because you only selected one window, and I hadn't yet implemented error handling. If you only select 1, if does full screen; if you select 2 it should do split screen.

Comment: Okay, I didn't select two at first, but now I have and at `set lastUI to last UI element` in `tell group "Spaces Bar"'s list 1` I get `error "System Events got an error: Can’t get group \"Mission Control\" of process \"Dock\"." number -1728 from group "Mission Control" of process "Dock"`. And yes, both windows selected can go into split screen together manually. I'll try it in macOS Mojave a little bit later and see what happens. Thanks! BTW I run multiple Desktops and have other Apps in full screen view, that may have an impact even though the two windows I select are on Desktop 1.

Comment: I've gotten that error once or twice myself during testing, and I suspect it's a race-condition issue: Either Mission Control or the Dock is busy when System Events tries to click the lastUI button, and things go to pot. You might try playing with delay commands: increase that last delay to one second, or put a half-second delay between assigning lastUI and trying to click it. or maybe skip the `click` and try a `perform action "AXPress"` instead. GUI-scripting is so kludgy...

Comment: Yeah, so true with GUI-scripting. Anyway, you've gotten farther than I ever did when I tried coming up with a programatic solution a while back. I'll play around with it a bit later and let you know. If I could up-vote the question again I would.

Comment: How would I call this with two app names and how could it also make sure those apps are running if they are not?

Comment: @MartinBraun: Change the line that starts `set selectedItems to choose from list...` to set the file names directly, like so: `set selectedItems to {"app name 1", "app name 1"}`. Then add a couple of lines to launch the app, e.g. `tell application (item 1 of selectedItems) to launch`.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [Ted Wrigley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56880436/12364174) above, but I would make the following changes:

```
(...)

tell application "System Events"
tell process "Dock"'s group "Mission Control"'s group 1
    tell group "Spaces Bar"'s list 1
        set countSpaces to count of UI elements
        set {p, s} to {position, size} of last UI element
        set XTarget to (item 1 of p) + (item 1 of s) + (100 * countSpaces)
        set YTarget to (item 2 of p) + (item 2 of s) + 100
    end tell
 
(...)
```

If you want to run this script multiple times, you need to count the number of open Spaces to correctly find the right spot to drag the window to. Otherwise, the windows are always are always dragged to the 2nd position of the Spaces Bar.