# Apple Script - How to move a window to a specific virtual workspace(desktop)

Tags: applescript

[image]

I would like to open 2 different Visual Studio Code windows and Move 1 to Desktop 2 and the second window to Desktop 3 using AppleScript.

Any help on this would be amazing. Thank you !

Comment: A while ago I wrote [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56880436/11722376) that GUI scripts Mission Control using Javascript. You could probably adapt it to your needs. Unfortunately MC is not directly scriptable, and AppleScript can't do clicks-drags without resorting to javascript. Give it a try and let me know if you run into problems.